# pandas merge(how="inner") result is bigger than both dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge, duplicates

I'm trying to find overlapping rows in two pandas DataFrames with the same columns, but different number of rows:

```
df1.shape
(187399, 784)

df2.shape
(9790, 784)
```

After the `pd.merge()` operation

```
common_cols = df1.columns.tolist()
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=common_cols, how="inner")
```

I get the result that is bigger than both df1 and df2

```
df3.shape
(283979, 784)
```

How is it possible and what am I doing wrong?
I have two dfs, both with 784 columns named `[0,1,2,3...783]` and different number of rows in each df. I just want to find the intersection of identical rows in these dfs. Meaning that if a row is present in `df1` and `df2`, it has to go to `df3` 
In a previous step I removed the duplicates from each df with `pd.drop_duplicates()`

Link to the jupyter notebook with code after the header "Problem 5"
[https://github.com/kuatroka/udacity_deep_learning/blob/master/1_notmnist-Copy1.ipynb](http://Link%20[link](https://github.com/kuatroka/udacity_deep_learning/blob/master/1_notmnist-Copy1.ipynb))

Comment: What happens if you merge without specifying `on=common_cols`?

Comment: check your data types of columns you are merging on to make sure the are exactly same

Comment: Cross Join is taking place

Comment: It sounds like you still have duplicate keys. How exactly did you call `drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: @ASGM - the same result as with it. @muon - all data types are the same. @ajcr - I created pd.DataFrame from numpy ndarray and removed duplicates by means of `df1 = pd.DataFrame(numpy_ndarray1).drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to post the solution to my own problem, but it was totally technical, not functional, therefore what @piRSquared was totally correct.

It turned out a very strange problem. In my conda installation I had Intel MKL module installed and by default it was on. This module supposedly improves speeds of numpy, scipy and scikit-learn. Once I disabled it with the CLI command `conda install nomkl` ,I got correct results from my very first code. I'm adding new tags for MKL in case someone else get this strange `numpy.merge()` behaviour
Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 1, 1], B=[9, 8, 7]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 1, 1], C=[6, 5, 4]))


print(df1)
print()
print(df2)

   A  B
0  1  9
1  1  8
2  1  7

   A  C
0  1  6
1  1  5
2  1  4
```

If we `merge` on column `'A'`, it will return a dataframe for every combination of rows where both column `'A'`s are equal to one.

```
df1.merge(df2)

   A  B  C
0  1  9  6
1  1  9  5
2  1  9  4
3  1  8  6
4  1  8  5
5  1  8  4
6  1  7  6
7  1  7  5
8  1  7  4
```

***Answer***
You have duplicate rows in both dataframes for the same keys you are merging on.

To solve that problem, you can (though you need to decide if this is appropriate for you)

```
df1.drop_duplicates(common_cols).merge(df2.drop_duplicates(common_cols))
```

Comment: I tried it. but I get the same exact number by adding your suggestion `drop_duplicates(common_cols)`. The thing is that all the columns are the same in both dfs. In your example you have A, B in df1 and A, C in df2, but in my case they are the same. Also I removed the duplicates in a previous step and I think it worked because the number of rows got reduced. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: @kuatroka ideally, you want to provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  We could hone in on the problem a lot quicker that way.

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared. Here is the link to a Jupyter Notebook which is part of the Udacity Deep Learning Course. I'm trying to solve the "Problem 5". the entire code is below the header "Problem 5", but you will need to follow the previous steps in the notebook as well. Main idea is to find overlapping rows in two data sets with images represented in binary form. I saw some people found a way to do it by hashing, but I'm sure numpy and pandas should have an easier way for this. Link [link](https://github.com/kuatroka/udacity_deep_learning/blob/master/1_notmnist-Copy1.ipynb)