# How to find interserction between two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1 with 200 000 records and df2 with 5 000 records.

Both dataframes have similar columns.
5000 records of df2 are present in df1.

When i check the intersection with below code:

```
s1 = pd.merge(result, df2, how='inner', on=['id'])
l2 = len(s1)
```

Here l2 (length of common records) is 5012 whereas is it should be 5000 because df2 has only 5000 records. i am finding only common records which are in df2 and df1.
I also tried dropping duplicates but same result

With the below code:

```
list_np=np.intersect1d(df1.id, df2.id).tolist()
len(list)
```

length of common records with this method is 4997.
Still 3 records difference is coming.
I am not able to understand how to resolve this.

Comment: does your df1 and df2 `id` columns have unique values? if you have duplicated values before merge, you might get more rows

Comment: yes they are unique , though i am also dropping duplicates before merge

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394450/pandas-mergehow-inner-result-is-bigger-than-both-dataframes (kuatroka's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably  have duplicate rows in both dataframes for the same keys you are merging on.

try to investigate:

```
uniqueValues_Df1 = df1['id'].unique()
diff_d1 = len(uniqueValues_Df1) - len(df1)
    
uniqueValues_Df2 = df2['id'].unique()
diff_d2 = len(uniqueValues_Df2) - len(df2)
```

diff_d1 / diff_d2  should be `0`.

Comment: diff_d1 is -15 and diff_d2 is -3 , but i am dropping the duplicates by df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'])
df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['id']) -- before merge , how shall i resolve this