# Merging dataframe (how = 'outer) but it's bigger than what it should be

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df (it's 2401 rows in actuality)

| Gene_ID | bulk_TPM |
| --- | --- |
| ENSG00000280614 | 246137.260000 |
| ENSG00000281181 | 246137.260000 |
| ENSG00000280800 | 246137.260000 |
| ENSG00000244734 | 242028.095764 |
| ENSG00000075624 | 159206.865330 |

df1 (24018 rows in actuality)

| Gene_ID | scRNA_TPM |
| --- | --- |
| ENSG00000166710 | 682.097012 |
| ENSG00000280614 | 0.002635 |
| ENSG00000281181 | 0.002635 |
| ENSG00000280800 | 0.002635 |
| ENSG00000244734 | 0.000000 |
| ENSG00000101076 | 0.000000 |
| ENSG00000277182 | 0.002635 |
| ENSG00000271978 | 0.002635 |
| ENSG00000263271 | 0.000000 |
| ENSG00000100565 | 0.000000 |

What I tried

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_merge = df.merge(df1, how='outer', indicator=True)
shared_df = df_merge[df_merge['_merge'].eq('both)].drop(columns=['_merge'])
shared_df
```

But when I run it the frame comes bigger than df size, should come out as 2401 rows but comes out 2405 instead

Comment: How do you know that its coming back with more than is expected? Do you know which 4 are there that shouldn't be? That might help in resolving why you are getting more than expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas merge(how="inner") result is bigger than both dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394450/pandas-mergehow-inner-result-is-bigger-than-both-dataframes)

Comment: This occurs because you have _duplicates_. And in some irony, [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43395271/1431750).

Comment: If you want only the rows which were present in `both` use an [`inner` join, which is the default](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html); instead of creating an outer join first and then filtering on `_merge='both'`.

Comment: @aneroid Do I need to use how ='inner' join when I just want to extract the intersection (shared elements) of the two data set?

Comment: @aneroid I don't think how = 'inner' is the right way to do it if I want to extract data that are in the intersection hence why I did how ='outer'

Comment: If you click on the [doc link above, and here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), you'll see that it says _"inner: use **intersection of keys** from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; preserve the order of the left keys."_ And if you're getting more rows than you think you should, then check each dataframe's `Gene_ID` for duplicates. If _each df_ as a pair of duplicates in the intersection, you'll get 4 rows instead of 1 or 2.