# When merging, the data frame becomes much larger

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a problem. I have two dataframes that I would like to merge with each other. The problem is that if I merge them together I get a MemoryError because the size of the dataframe has grown many times. I have found the following article I looked at [pandas merge(how="inner") result is bigger than both dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394450/pandas-mergehow-inner-result-is-bigger-than-both-dataframes). I still can't merge them at all because I'm running out of memory.

Is there an option to just merge the first element and ignore the other duplicates?

For example, my dataframe `df_1` is structured like this (see below)
Is there an option that `df_2` only writes its values in and if there are duplicates these are simply ignored?

Dataframe `df_1`

```py
id_x  B   C  id_y new_column
1     4   9  1    a
2     5   8  2    b
3     6   7  3    c
3     6   7  3    z # should be ignored
```

```py
df_merged= pd.merge(df_1,
                    df_2, how='inner',
                    left_on=['id_x'], right_on=['id_y'],
                    suffixes=['', '_right'])
```

Comment: Can you give an example like you posted above, but the df2 portion?

Comment: you can always select the columns from either of the dataframe when merging, to reduce the total count of the columns

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like df_2 must have multiple values for id=3. You could use drop duplicates with a subset of columns for df_2 before the merge (or within the merge). Something like `pd.merge(df_1,df_2.drop_duplicates(subset=['id_y']), how='inner',left_on=['id_x'], right_on=['id_y'],suffixes=['', '_right'])`. This will make sure that df_2 only has 1 value for each id_y and won't fan out the join.